# A "Dimension too large" error with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw some dependence in function of years. The real functionality uses `\addplot table` and works fine. However, when I want to draw some simple objects over it (just uncomment some of the lines) I receive a "Dimension too large" error. What do I wrong?

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}               
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
xmin=1993, xmax=2020,% x scale
ymin=1e2, ymax=1e8, % y scale
xlabel=Year,
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
ylabel=$Gain$,
ymode=log,
]

%   \draw[thin,gray] (1993,1e3) -- (2011,1e7);
%   \draw[thin,gray] (2010,1e7) -- (2018,1e7);
%   \draw[thick,red] (2014,3e6) circle(1.5cm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either switch to a reasonably new compatibility (recommended) or work with `axis cs:`.

```
\documentclass[article]{standalone}               
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
xmin=1993, xmax=2020,% x scale
ymin=1e2, ymax=1e8, % y scale
xlabel=Year,
/pgf/number format/1000 sep={},
ylabel=$Gain$,
ymode=log,
]

  \draw[thin,gray] (1993,1e3) -- (2011,1e7);
  \draw[thin,gray] (2010,1e7) -- (2018,1e7);
  \draw[thick,red] (2014,3e6) circle(1.5cm);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]